# Find the name of a component in Backoffice of SAP Commerce / Hybris

Tags: components, sap-commerce-cloud, commerce, backoffice

I am trying to add an action to one of the toolbars in the Hybris backoffice. However, in order to achieve that I would need to modify the component and add an action to it in the backoffice.xml. The problem is that for all the other modifications I see components like editorarea, listviewaction, editorareaaction etc and I have no clue what the name of my exact component is (it`s something about the collaboration center). I would like to know if there is a way to check from the backoffice, or somehow, which component is which, so next time I know how to modify it. Can someone help please?

Comment: You can share some screenshots where you want to add action. You can also check Application Orchestrator to find out widgets and components. https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8b5479bd86691014bb26ade6959b0505.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the Application Orchestrator and it definitely helped, but I still have no progress on the issue above. I want to add an action to the collaboration center. The thing is that I already have done something similar but for listviewactions or editorareaactions components. However, I don`t know how to find the name of that exact toolbar, so I can edit it in the backoffice-config.xml.